# Page number appears even if I use plain option

Tags: beamer, numbering, page-numbering, slideshow

I am struggling around the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{default}      % nebo zkuste Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw,...
 \usecolortheme{default} % nebo zkuste albatross, beaver, crane, ...
 \usefonttheme{default}  % nebo zkuste serif, structurebold, ...
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] % to number

\usepackage{verbatim}

%%% PAGE NUMBERING

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{page number appendix}
{%
 \hfill%
 \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
 \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
 \insertpagenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\newenvironment{myframe}{
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}}
{\end{frame}}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{ \hspace{2em} \usebeamerfont{footline}%
   \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber }

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
 \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Even if I specify `[noframenumbering,plain]` the page appears like this: [image]
Notice the numbering appearing at the end of the page semi-hidden. So it seems that the plain option is here only "partially hiding" the page numbering. Why? Am I doing something wrong? I would like the page numbering not to appear at all in some of the slides.

Thank you,

Federico

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}` does not show the page number.  Probably works for frame too.

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing the `navigation symbols` template to show the page number. This template is shown on all frames, no matter if they are `plain` or not.

If you want your frame number to respect `plain` frame, place them in the footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{default}      % nebo zkuste Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw,...
 \usecolortheme{default} % nebo zkuste albatross, beaver, crane, ...
 \usefonttheme{default}  % nebo zkuste serif, structurebold, ...
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] % to number

\usepackage{verbatim}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```